# Disable deleting child records entries when deleting parent

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have **User** class, which has collection of Roles represented by SQL view in database (read only).
So, User can has a collection of Roles, which are supplied outside and cannot be changed by User's object.
I have to live with that and can't change the design.

**The issue is:** When **User's** object is being deleted, Hibernate tries to also remove User's ID from enclosing tables and fails on removing user Id from **Role's** view.

**The question:** Is there any way to prevent Hibernate from removing User's id from enclosing tables (i.e. from **User's** **Roles** view)?

For now the application just falls with critical error when deleting User, because v_user_roles is read only, so DB refuses Hibernate's try to delete any records from it.

From the log:

```
delete from mapp.user_locations where user_id=?  OK
delete from mapp.user_adresses where user_id=?  OK
delete from mapp.v_user_roles where user_id=? FAIL, I want to avoid this
```

P.S. Tried "Immutable", CascadeType.PERSIST, "nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false", disabling setters - without success.

**User's entity:**

```
@Table(name = "users", schema = "PROD")
public class User extends EntityWithIdAbst implements UserDetails {

    @Column(name = "USERNAME", nullable = false)
    private String username;

    @JsonIgnore
    @Column(name = "USERPASS", nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @Immutable
    @ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "v_user_roles", schema = "PROD",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false) ,
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "cur_role_id", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    ) @Getter
    private Set<Role> rolesInherited;
```

**Controller:**
*It simply calls PagingAndSortingRepository's deleteById(id) method via Service for User object*

```
@ResponseBody
@DeleteMapping(value = "/delete/{id}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<HttpResponseWithStatus> delete (E entity) {
    HttpResponseWithStatus resp = new HttpResponseWithStatus().setHttpStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    try {
        aService.deleteById(entity.getId());
...
```

**Service:**

```
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl extends PagingAndSortingRepository implements UserService {
...
    public void deleteById(Long id) {
        rep.deleteById(id);
    }
***
```

Answer (score 0):

> The issue is: When User's object are being deleted

Can you show the code that you use? This is not very specific. Maybe you use `entityManager.remove` on some object that uses delete cascading or orphan removal. If you use a delete query, this could also be a bug. In that case I'd recommend you try to reproduce the issue with e.g. https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-test-case-templates and post it to the issue tracker: http://hibernate.atlassian.net/

Comment: I'm using plain deleteById(id) method of JPA PagingAndSortingRepository's . Added an appropriate code snippet to my initial post.

Comment: I just re-read the question and don't see what the problem is. You are deleting a user so Hibernate must cleanup the join table `v_user_roles`, otherwise you'd get a constraint violation exception.

Comment: The problem is: v_user_roles is read-only and supplied from external source. So even if User deleted, this view must be left intact and I'm searching for option to do it. 
The problem in general is: for now the application falls with critical error when deleting User, because v_user_roles is read only, so DB refuses Hibernate's try to delete any records from it.

Comment: So there is no way for you to model this mapping differently i.e. without the view? In the end, the assignment from user to role has to be deleted somehow, so however the view implemented, this has to be cleaned up somehow. It might be possible to model this through a OneToMany relationship which isn't cleaned up by default instead.

Comment: If I abandon from that view, I have to implement recursive role assignment. It wasn't in my team's plans, but if there is no other way, we'll think about it. Thank you.